# Экранирование символов php

Tags: php, экранирование

Вопрос в следующем:
Есть несколько строк кода для отправки через json (т.е. строкой). Так как в html  "+" является знаком конкатенации, язык разметки его просто сжирает и плюсик теряется. С этим разобрался. С кавычками не до конца смог.
Пример 1 (все ок):

```
$text = 'Some "hard" text';
```

т.к. кавычки разного формата, пропускает.
Но если взять пример 2:

```
$text = 'Some 'hard' text';
```

php ругается, т.к. думает, что кавычка перед hard - конец строки.
Собственно, не удается даже создать текст в таком виде.
Приблизительный код следующий:

```
$text = 'Some "ha'+'rd" text';
$patterns = array("/\+/","/\‘/","/\’/","/\“/","/\”/");
$replacements = array("%2B","%91","%92","%93","%94");
$text = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```

Текст берется с текстового поля ввода, и перед каждым символом вставлять "\" никто не будет.
Как сделать возможным содержание в тексте кавычек - одинаковых с теми, что служат началом и концом строки?
т.е. так:

```
$text = 'Some 'hard' text';
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А в чем вопрос то? что в итоге нужно? на php можно просто заменить все кавычки на их экранированый вариант **$inputStr=str_replace('\'','\\\'',$inputStr);**

Comment: `Так как в html "+" является знаком конкатенации` это как так? Конкатенация - это операция слияния строк, а HTML - не язык программирования. Функцию `htmlspecialchars` знаете?

Comment: Вернее сказать не html, а в строке...

Comment: Переформулируйте свой вопрос: что пытаетесь сделать, и как. Из того что написано сейчас, ни понятно ровным счетом ничего.

Comment: На одном сайте есть форма для заполнения, в форме есть несколько полей, которые посредством php отправляются на другой сайт. Т.е. это текст, и там порой бывает что угодно, таблицы и т.д. Дело в том, что если внутри текста имеются двойные кавычки - все происходит нормально, т.к. строка находится внутри одинарных кавычек. А когда в тексте появляется одинарная кавычка - php останавливается на ней, считая это концом строки\текста. На сколько я понимаю, нужно каким то образом дать понять php, что если после кавычек еще есть текст - продолжать его читать до тех пор, пока не будет символ - ;

Comment: @MorozovVladyslav [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) вам в помощь

Comment: На сколько понимаю, это похоже на preg_match (тоже преобразование).
Я не могу ничего использовать, т.к. php не может обработать строку. Например, такую:
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href="test">Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
Кавычки одинаковые, не разные

Comment: @MorozovVladyslav preg_match - поиск, и ничего совместного с заменной не имеет, Вы путаете с preg_replace

Comment: @MorozovVladyslav покажите какая у вас форма, какие данные Вы высылаете, какой ответ приходит

Comment: Да, имел ввиду preg_replace. Допустим есть обычное пользовательское поле ввода, содержание которого нужно будет передать в переменную. Будет ошибка, если внутри будут кавычки такие же как и те, что содержат строку. В php же строка в формате $var = "text"; как сделать возможным содержание в данной строке так же двойных кавычек?

Comment: @MorozovVladyslav Не совсем все ясно, так как при высылании формы, все что в ней кодируеться, и передаеться в закодированом формате, так что без разницы что будет внутри, оно все равно дойдет в таком же формате до PHP, остаеться открытым вопрос, как у Вас выглядит форма, какие данные Вы передаете, почему Вы считаете что данные теряються именно при высылании?

Comment: Дошло, попробую - отпишу.

Comment: Это бизнес процесс в битрикс. Попробовал, возвращает значение null переменной.
Возможно, не установлено ENT_QUOTES... Как это проверить?

Answer (score 1):

В PHP "+" означает добавление (операция с числами), конкатенация обозначается символом "." (точка), а если Вы хотите использовать кавычки, в таких же кавычках, хватит перед ними поставить обратный слэш:

```
$text = 'Some \'hard\' text';
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, но все было не то. Решил heredoc-синтаксисом:

```
$bar = <<<EOT
"Двойные кавычки" 'Одинарные' и куча символов <>?!@#$%^&*()_+_=
EOT;
echo $bar;
```